# Ionic. Apps is not changing after ionic live deploy

Tags: ionic3

i have followed the [Ionic Deploy Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/setup/#usage)

1. installed the cordova plugin
2. set the app id and the channel name  of --variable ionic cordova plugin
3. git flow project to ionic
4. my commit version is on ionic
5. deploy/assign the version to the channel
6. ionic cordova build android
7. install to my android
8. do changes on code (like html), and git flow again
9. assign the latest commit version to the channel
10. kill the apps then reopen apps in android (i select update mode to auto)
11. nothing change

i did so many times wasting 5 hours..

then i tried the [Pro client](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/plugin-api.html). it works, it reads my channel info, my version number, but it says the no deploy info available

{deploy_uuid: "NO_DEPLOY_AVAILABLE", channel: "Production", binary_version: "1.9.08"}

please help. im clueless, 5 hours wasted

Comment: What is the command that u are using to deploy to android

Comment: ionic cordova build android --debug, it generates unsigned apk. @yash_DedSec

Comment: any answer? im the same problem  The "Deploy binary_version" is correct but that is binary version. We need to know live deploy version. This will help us to make sure user has proper version. So i do some research about how we can detect live deploy version as "uuid" to me wrong as well as this is just unique code. We need to get proper live deploy version.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi  ionic doesnt  provide that. to overcome this can use your own "deploy code" for each new live update that shown in some page i.e. setting page or about page